# Set the thickness of highcharter column chart columns in R

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I wonder if there is a way to set the thickness of a highcharter columns of a column chart in R.

```
library(highcharter)
pokemon%>%
  count(type_1)%>%
  arrange(n)%>%
  hchart(type = "column", hcaes(x = type_1, y = n))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [pointWidth](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointWidth) option:

```
pokemon%>%
  count(type_1)%>%
  arrange(n)%>%
  hchart(type = "column", hcaes(x = type_1, y = n)) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(pointWidth = 100))
```